# Is it possible to reset a value on a table depending on when It was created on mysql

Tags: mysql, raspberry-pi

I am fairly new to mysql.

I am creating a login system, and I want to create a reset password option for the user. Every time the user requests for a password reset a code is created and I want to reset this code every 12 hours after it has been created.

I am running a `LAMP` server on a raspberry pi 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple approach would be to also maintain datetime column in the user table, which records the server time when a particular reset token were created.  Then, in your database logic, you would compare that timestamp against the current time, and assert that no more than 12 hours have passed.  If the token has expired, then just return `NULL` from your query, and then handle the `NULL` value in your server side application logic as a failure.

I don't recommend trying to configure MySQL to manage this logic (though it might be possible to do so).  A database is designed to store data, not so much to manage it, the latter which is the responsibility of the application, or maybe a DBA.

Comment: Should I do this by using a event which will check the datetime column

Comment: No events.  When your user submits his reset token to the backend, you do an additional check to make sure the token is not stale.